# How are Maxwell equations satisfied when inelastic scattering occurs?

Tags: scattering, maxwell-equations, raman-spectroscopy

Consider two media, A and B (example air/dieletric). One [finds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields) conditions that the $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ fields must satisfy at the interface, namely $\hat n_\text{A-B}\times(\vec E_A-\vec E_B) = \vec 0$ and $\hat n_\text{A-B}\cdot(\vec B_A-\vec B_B) = 0$.

Now consider an incident electromagnetic field from medium A to medium B. To keep things simple, consider a plane wave (could be an approximation to a laser). It turns that, that for the above interface conditions to be true at all times, the frequency of the incident, reflected and refracted waves must match.*

However it is well known that inelastic scattering occur for many materials. An example is [Raman scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_scattering) which is used in laboratories where a laser is shun upon a material. The reflected light frequency difference with respect to the incident laser own frequency is then analyzed, revealing information about said material.

I do not understand how are Maxwell equations satisfied when such a scattering occur. I know they still are, but I am unable to see it for example from the interface conditions I have written above. How can $\omega$ differ in the incident and reflected waves while still satisfying the interface conditions?

---

*Because $\vec E( r,t)=\vec{E_0}e^{i(\omega t-\vec k \cdot \vec r)}$ and for such two waves to be equal at all times require the argument multiplying $t$ to match, i.e. $\omega$ is the same.

Comment: Surface enhanced Raman occurs precisely because Maxwell's equations are satisfied.

Comment: I know Maxwell equations are satisfied, like I wrote in my post. I do not understand the relevance of your comment. Can you please provide more details?